# "Could not cast" error in XCTest when loading from storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, storyboard

I'm trying to load one of our custom view controllers in a XCTest:

```
let myViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewControllerID") as! MyCustomViewController
```

I'm getting this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.MyCustomViewController'
>   (0x10852b720) to 'MyApp.MyCustomViewController' (0x11a7330a0).

I'm using Xcode 7.1.1

None of the solutions to this problem that I found online fix it.

Any idea? We can't unit test ANY of our view controllers.

Comment: What happens if you remove the cast?

Comment: It works, but I can't use it, as the compiler doesn't know that the view is a MyCustomViewController one when Im writing the code

Comment: What happens if you do `let myViewController:MyCustomViewController = storyboard...` without the cast?

Comment: "Cannot convert" error when building

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24237609/1630618

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this to the top of your XCTest file

`@testable import ModuleName`

and also remove the target memberships of your Storyboard and ViewController to the test target if they are set

Comment: the `remove the target memberships` part helped in my case, thanks!